# Expansion Android Apk working very slow whenever downloading first time

Tags: android, performance, apk-expansion-files

Currently, I am using this plugin

```
https://github.com/erobertson42/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/tree/cordova-9
```

I am using this path to show the image -

```
'content://com.x.x/main_expansion/assets/dummy.png';
```

and to make image path safe I am using domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl method

```
 getImg(img) {
        img = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(img);
        return img;
    }
```

Whenever I am using my app, it is working very slow but I am going one by one on the screen throughout the app first time it stucks on every screen approx 40 to 60seconds but after taking sometime it will work normally. If anybody has any suggestion or concern, please share

Comment: you need both: to profile your app and to show your code.

Comment: What about profiling the app?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko sorry not getting you?

Comment: profiler is a tool to check which method calls take time, which objects take memory, etc.

Comment: yes I saw that and it is working fine whenever I am taping on a point
do you have any solution for this issue?

Comment: solution is to profile your application. It has nothing related to what you wrote in your last comment

Comment: Yes I have checked that but there is nothing wrong I can see there, So I am asking is there any solution for this issue?